# ASP.NET MVC 4 method to maintain scroll position after ajax update

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, scroll

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 view, I have a div "below the fold" that may be updated using AJAX.  Even with the async update, the browser scrolls to the top of the page.

It seems there are several javascript solutions available (none of which I've gotten to work), but has anyone come up with a MVC solution for this challenge ... particularly anything like the web.UI solution with RequestPageManager in "old style" (haha) asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JQuery ajax() call ?

It will be like following

```
        function update() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'Page2.aspx/GetData',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                //This is where you update the div alert(data.d);

            }
        });
    }
```

I have pulled above code from online. Didn't test though. Just wanted to give an idea.

Comment: Yes even the jquery.ajax call causes the page to shift back to the top when the div is low enough on the page to require a scroll down to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to me that the browser would scroll merely because you updated the page with content received from an AJAX call.

However, I can think of a few situations where this might happen:

1) the ajax call was initiated from a click event bound to an "a" tag with an "href" attribute set to "#" as in: <a href="#"> this is a link</a>.  If you did not call preventDefault inside of the click event, the browser will "visit" the "#" link and cause the browser to scroll to the top of the page.

2) the browser had focus on an element that was below the inserted content from the ajax call.  In this case, the added ajax content was long enough to cause the browser to move to keep focus on the element that previously had focus.

If either of these reasons do not apply, please provide more information to diagnose your issue.